# bitcoind only accept the RPC for 127.0.0.1 but the actually ip address

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I use the exact same command, one use 127.0.0.1, and the other use 192.168.3.126, only the first one could succeed. Anyone here has met a similar issue before?

```
curl --user root --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getblockchaininfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
Enter host password for user 'root':
{"result":{"chain":"main","blocks":205269,"headers":571040,"bestblockhash":"0000000000000508cceb43c817c744e04c557e34799391d5768cbf081cd0e7f2","difficulty":3072321.732020756,"mediantime":1351359250,"verificationprogress":0.02469030455221953,"chainwork":"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e6f6192f0e1ddb53e","pruned":false,"softforks":[{"id":"bip34","version":2,"reject":{"status":false}},{"id":"bip66","version":3,"reject":{"status":false}},{"id":"bip65","version":4,"reject":{"status":false}}],"bip9_softforks":{"csv":{"status":"defined","startTime":1462060800,"timeout":1493596800,"since":0}}},"error":null,"id":"curltest"}

curl --user root --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getblockchaininfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://192.168.3.126:8332/
Enter host password for user 'root':
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.3.126 port 8332: Connection refused
```

This is my bitcoin.conf

```
# location to store blockchain and other data.
datadir=/mnt/hgfs/vmware/data

dbcache=4000
# Must set txindex=1 so Bitcoin keeps the full index
txindex=1

# [rpc]
# Accept command line and JSON-RPC commands.
server=1
# Default Username and Password for JSON-RPC connections
rpcuser=root
rpcpassword=bitcoin

# If you want to allow remote JSON-RPC access
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
# [wallet]
disablewallet=1

# [ZeroMQ]
# ZeroMQ messages power the realtime Planaria crawler
# so it's important to set the endpoint
zmqpubhashtx=tcp://192.168.3.126:28332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://192.168.3.126:28332

# BitDB makes heavy use of JSON-RPC so it's set to a higher number
# But you can tweak this number as you want
rpcworkqueue=512
```

This is my ip address setup

```
ifconfig -a
br-76ed1d5730c4: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:5fff:feb2:2046  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:5f:b2:20:46  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2628  bytes 1531664 (1.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2732  bytes 3293621 (3.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-f5226cc26810: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:58ff:fe87:853c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:58:87:85:3c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1267140  bytes 83830921 (83.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1262839  bytes 2246455481 (2.2 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:9c:ed:2f:9c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.3.126  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.3.255
        inet6 fe80::e064:468a:3938:cd2b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:66:2e:d9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 30775030  bytes 45032478812 (45.0 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8445739  bytes 637881701 (637.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3321  bytes 292466 (292.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3321  bytes 292466 (292.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need rpcbind=[Your IP] in the config

Answer (score 1):

Does adding

```
rpcallowip=192.168.3.126
```

to you `bitcoin.conf` help? By default, connections coming from addresses other than localhost are declined.